# Initialize a numpy array to save other arrays in it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My goal is it to save 2 different arrays in a new numpy array.

I tried a few things and this worked for me:

```
state_vek = np.array([array1, array2])
```

`array1` and `array2` are have different dimensions.

But as i am working with classes i would need to initialize state_vek beforehand.

Then I tried this:

```
state_vek = np.zeros(2)
state_vek[0] = array1
state_vek[1] = array2
```

Which resulted in following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

So my question is, how am i supposed to initialize my state_vek so i can use this line `state_vek[0] = array1`?

Comment: What, exactly is the result you are looking for? If you want to be able to store any arbitrary array, *just use a list*.

Comment: In the first case what's the shape of the two arrays and the result?  What's their dtypes?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 
My goal is it to use the array or list as input for a neural network. The first array is a (4,160,120,1) array which gets passed to an convolutional neural network as input 
The output of this CNN gets flattened into an long array and then i wanted to append array2 to that flattened array.
The storing of the states is also done via numpy arrays that why i would like an solution with numpy array. Im aware of the existance of lists

Comment: An object dtype array is no better, and often worse, than a list with the same components.  So far you problem description is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimensions of array1 and array2 beforehand, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])
arr2 = np.array([4,5,6])
b = np.zeros((2,3)) #np.zeros(shape, dtype = None, order = 'C')

b[0] = arr1
b[1] = arr2
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6.]]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. How would you do that if array1 had the shape of (4,160,120,1) and array2 had the shape of (1,)?

Comment: Just use python lists to store, and convert in numpy arrays using asarray() function when you want to perform any operations.